# how to get the selected index from a getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the selected index from a getElementByClassName.

I know how can I get it from Id but somehow its not working for ClassName..

```
   document.getElementById("Metriclayer").selectedIndex = abc;
```

like this how can I get it for document.getElementByClassName.

I want to set the value of abc( its an integer) in the selected index of `document.getElementByClassName("MetricClass").`

How can I do that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function `getElementByClassName`, the function is `getElementsByClassName`. As you can see, `Elements` is plural, so it returns a collection of all elements with that class, not a single element. You need to index the collection. If you want the first (or only) element of the collection, use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("MetricClass")[0].selectedIndex = abc;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/685sa7fs/5/)

If you want to operate on all of them, write a loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("MetricClass");
for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    elements[i].selectedIndex = abc;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar - Metriclayer is a class name for a combo box and I want to save the value of abc(say 2) in  document.getElementsByClassName("Metriclayer")[0].selectedIndex = abc; and then later want to retrieve it as well like abc= document.getElementsByClassName("Metriclayer")[0].selectedIndex

Comment: this is not working as I am not able to get the particular selected index after retrieving it

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/685sa7fs/3/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByClassName` does not exist, since it would be pointless - there can be zero-to-many elements with the same class name in a single document. The correct plural function name is `document.getElementsByClassName`. Since this returns an array of elements, not a single one, more processing is required to get a useful result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('MetricClass');
var index0 = el[0].selectedIndex;
```